# How to Do a contentInset on a NSScrollView on a Mac

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I am trying to do a contentInset on an NSScrollView the same way as iOS in a UIScrollView. There is no method to do this though. Is there anyway to achieve this? this picture should describe what I am trying to do:

[image]

If anyone knows of a solution I would absolutely love to hear!! It's driving me nuts

Comment: The picture does not describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes it does. When scrolled to the top, the grid is inset so that the navigation bar does not cover it up.

Comment: @Blakeasd did you ever figure out how to do this? I need to do the same thing.

Comment: @xizor nope, never could figure out how to do it. :/

Comment: @Blakeasd Ouch, thanks though.

Answer (score 24):

You should try something like this

```
scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = NO;
scrollView.contentInsets = NSEdgeInsetsMake(offset, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: These properties are only available in OS X 10.10.

Comment: Also, after doing that you might have to add `scrollView.contentView.scrollToPoint(NSMakePoint(0, -offset))` to scroll to the top as the initial scrolling position will be off once the `contentInset` is changed.